# Write the output of Server connected by Telnet on Client

Tags: java, sockets, client, telnet

I am writing a java program using apache common libraries for telnet. I want to connect to a router using telnet. Now i want to send certain commands from client to server without actually giving control to server and retrieve the output on server to my local client machine. It is similar to socket programming where i send something from client and the server replies from there. But we did write server java program. Here i cannot write a server program to send me the output on my machine. Provide any solution for this.

Comment: Usually if you (ligitimately) connect to (telnet) server the server will reply to commands you issue to it. If you are trying to "fake" you IP address (the only reason why you would not see the responses) then you will need to learn about it yourself.

Comment: I can get the output by logging myself to the remote server but what i want is that i send my commands from my local which will be executed on server and the output will be displayed on my local.
That's similar to the simple socket programming we perform using TCP or UDP.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what you will get if you connect to your server (router in your case). If your server accepts connection and commands it will respond on your connection I/O channels exactly as with client/server because that is precisely what it is.